# "Gleams of varnished spirits" in Conrad's 'Heart of Darkness'

Tags: meaning

I am reading *Heart of Darkness* by Joseph Conrad and its prose includes the following:

> The sea-reach of the Thames stretched before us like the beginning of an interminable waterway. In the offing the sea and the sky were welded together without a joint, and in the luminous space the tanned sails of the barges drifting up with the tide seemed to stand still in red clusters of canvas sharply peaked, **with gleams of varnished sprits**.  A haze rested on the low shores that ran out to sea in vanishing flatness. The air was dark above Gravesend, and farther back still seemed condensed into a mournful gloom, brooding motionless over the biggest, and the greatest, town on earth.

I can't get what means "with gleams of varnished spirits."

Is it talking about spirits in the sense of Holy Spirit, of a Ghost or what?

Comment: It's not *spirits,* it's *[sprits](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sprit),* right in your quotation. As in bowsprits, which like other spars were given a glossy protective coating of spar varnish.

Comment: I edited your question to get the correct text. It is *sprits* not *spirits*.

Comment: Bad on Conrad. Nothing gleams under those conditions. [Image](http://thamessailingbargeparade.com/img/thalatta.jpg) showing old  Thames sailing barge. The sprit is holding the main peak up and out.

Comment: Just to clarify this: the error is not santimirandarp 's. It is a misprint in quite a few editions of "Heart of Darkness".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Spirits" is a typo for "sprits". This is a technical term in nautical usage, defined in the OED as:

> ‘A small boom or pole which crosses the sail of a boat diagonally from
>   the mast to the upper hindmost corner of the sail, which it is used to
>   extend and elevate’

Comment: The OED actually quotes Falconer

Comment: @Clare. Correct.

Comment: Which explains the varnishing

Comment: Good..here an image https://www.google.com.ar/search?rlz=1CDGOYI_enAR610AR610&hl=es&biw=320&bih=492&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=c2XiWbj6IYGcwgTSnoPwDg&q=sprit+boat&oq=sprit+boat&gs_l=mobile-gws-img.3..0i19k1l2j0i13i5i30i19k1l3.10119.12317.0.12840.7.7.0.0.0.0.426.1639.0j2j3j0j1.6.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-img..2.5.1340...35i39k1j0i8i10i30k1j0i10i24k1j0i10i19k1j0i8i30i19k1.1442.BE7ischSb0o#imgrc=bPFAejRB2DrB8M: thanks..